# How can I auto adjust the width of a GD-generated image to fit the text?

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to display a number using GD. This number changes, so sometimes the width needs to change. Is there a way to calculate how wide the text will be so that I can dynamically set the width?

Comment: this could be helpful http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=377317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can find out the dimensions of a text using [`imagettfbbox()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) (or [`imageftbbox()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php) if you're using Freetype).