# How can I trim just the left and right side of an image using Imagemagick in PHP?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to trim a variable amount of whitespace in an image only the left and right side using ImageMagick and PHP.  Does anyone know how to do this (perhaps using something other than imagemagick?)?

Here's an example.

I have these two images:
[image: Test]

[image: Test Again]
Each has a variable amount of text that is dynamically created in a fixed width image.
What I need to do is trim the background off the right and left side so the images come out like this:
[image: TestResult]
[image: Test Again Result]

If ImageMagick can't do it, I am willing to use something else, but I will need help on how exactly because I am not much of a programmer.  Thanks!

Here's my current code that trims all sides of an image:

```
<?php
/* Create the object and read the image in */
$i = '3';
$im = new Imagick("test".$i.".png");

/* Trim the image. */
$im->trimImage(0);

/* Ouput the image */
//header("Content-Type: image/" . $im->getImageFormat());
//echo $im;
/*** Write the trimmed image to disk ***/
$im->writeImage(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test'.$i.'.png');
/*Display Image*/
echo $img = "<img src=\"test".$i.".png\">";
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see in the ImageMagick docs on [cropping and borders](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#shave), it doesn't seem to be possible.

you can't specify an edge for "intelligent" cropping (known as`-trim` on the command line), and all the cropping methods that accept a geometry argument need a fixed number for cropping.

The only idea that comes to mind is to get the colour of the shaved area in a separate call, run `trimImage`, and add the lost areas back using `-border`.

> **Edit:** The IM manual is suggesting something similar. Check out [Trimming Just One Side of an Image.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim) I'm not familiar with IM's PHP extension to translate the code into PHP calls but it should be half-way straightforward.

Comment: I was able to trim the right and left side of an image using this code: exec('convert test4.png  -gravity West -background white -splice 5x0 -background black -splice 5x0  -trim +repage -chop 5x0  test44.png');  Thank you!
exec('convert test44.png -gravity East -background white -splice 1x0  -background black -splice 1x0 -trim  +repage -chop 1x0   test44.png');

Comment: You can also combine trimming sides into one command (which is more efficient and will provide better quality), e.g., for right and bottom margins: `convert  -gravity North -background white -splice 0x1 -trim +repage -chop 0x1  -gravity West -background white -splice 1x0 -trim +repage -chop 1x0 <input> <output>`

Comment: the above command adds a white line down the middle of the image? :(

Answer (score 21):

I think you are on the right track with `ImageMagick`'s `-trim` operator <sup>1)</sup>, but the trick would be to get it tell you what it *would* do without *actually* doing it, and then modify that to do what you really want...

So, to get the trim-box `ImageMagick` calculates for your first image, you do this:

```
convert -fuzz 10% image.jpg -format "%@" info:
60x29+21+31
```

That is a 60x29 pixel rectangle, offset 21 across and 31 down from the top left corner. Now, we want to get these values into `bash` variables, so I set the IFS (Input Field Separator) to split fields on spaces, `x` and also `+` signs:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=" x+" read a b c d < <(convert -fuzz 10% image.jpg -format "%@" info:)

echo $a $b $c $d
60 29 21 31
```

Now I can ignore the `29` and the `31` because we are only interested in cropping the width, and crop like this:

```
convert image.jpg -crop "${a}x+${c}+0" out.jpg
```

So, for your 2 images, I get these:

[image]
[image]

and the full procedure is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=" x+" read a b c d < <(convert -fuzz 10% image.jpg -format "%@" info:)
convert image.jpg -crop "${a}x+${c}+0" out.jpg
```

**Notes**

1) The `-format %@` is just a shorthand for the `-trim` operator, which would be this in full

```
convert image.jpg -trim info:
image.jpg JPEG 72x40 200x100+16+24 8-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation and answer. Works smooth as silk. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

The GD based library [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) has something similar. It's called `autoCrop`, by default it works on all four sides.

However, you could just add another parameter and based on it only crop top/bottom or left/right.

[autoCrop code](http://wideimage.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wideimage/trunk/lib/Operation/AutoCrop.php?revision=281&view=markup)

It's pretty well documented. `$img` is a `WideImage_Image` type. There is also an [interactive online demo of it](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/wp-content/current/demo/index.php?demo=autoCrop&output=preset%20for%20demo&colors=255&dither=1&match_palette=1).

Related question: [Removing black bars off video thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7938789/367456).

Comment: As an additional comment: You can use that library and cut off all sides, then use the same library to center the cropped image onto a another picture that has the right height (and same width as the cropped image) with the background color in question. Job done (if the text was originally centered on y-axis).

Comment: This looks like it will work (I have WideImage up and running) - but I am not sure how to add another parameter to only autocrop the left and right sides of an image.  Could you supply code?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using GD:

```
function imageautocrop( &$img) {
    $emptycol = function ( $img, $x, $min, $max) {
        for( $y=$min; $y<$max; $y++) {
            $col = imagecolorsforindex( $img, imagecolorat( $img, $x, $y));
            if( $col['alpha'] != 127) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    $trim = Array('top'=>0,'bot'=>0,'lft'=>0,'rgt'=>0);
    $size = Array('x'=>imagesx($img)-1,'y'=>imagesy($img)-1);
    // code for affecting rows removed due to question asked
    while( $emptycol( $img, $trim['lft'], $trim['top'], $size['y']-$trim['bot'])) $trim['lft']++;
    while( $emptycol( $img, $size['x']-$trim['rgt'], $trim['top'], $size['y']-$trim['bot'])) $trim['rgt']++;
    $newimg = imagecreate( $size['x']-$trim['lft']-$trim['rgt']+1, $size['y']-$trim['top']-$trim['bot']+1);
    imagecopy( $newimg, $img, 0, 0, $trim['lft'], $trim['top'], imagesx($newimg)+1, imagesy($newimg)+1);
    imagedestroy($img);
    $img = $newimg;
}
```

It's very old code of mine, so probably not optimal, but it does the job.

Comment: I've tried to use your code, but I can't get it to work...like I said I am not much of a programmer.  Could you give me lines to load an image and then write changes to the image?  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: `$img = imagecreatefrompng("FILENAME.png"); imageautocrop($img); imagepng($img,"NEWFILENAME.png");`

Answer (score 0):

It is a two step process as text is dynamically generated

- Generate the text image, determine width(image)
- Overlay text image into background, determine width(background)
- Use one tool mentioned above, crop (width(background)-width(image)/2 on either side

The trick is figuring out the width(image). See: [How can I auto adjust the width of a GD-generated image to fit the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485630/how-can-i-auto-adjust-the-width-of-a-gd-generated-image-to-fit-the-text)

Then again, if you know width(image), you can crop the width(background) first before overlay

Answer (score -2):

Use cropImage() instead. Something like this, perhaps:

```
$img_x_size = 800;    // Set these to relevant values
$img_y_size = 600;

$crop_pixels = 20;    // How many pixels to crop

// cropImage(XsizeOfCrop, YsizeOfCrop, CropXPos, CropYPos)
$im->cropImage($img_x_size - $crop_pixels, $img_y_size, 0, $crop_pixels / 2);
```

Comment: The problem with this (if I am understanding crop_pixels correctly) is that it only removes a fixed amount of pixels - trimImage actually crops the image until it comes up against something other than the background color (so as to make the image as small as possible).  So I don't think this will work....I added clarity to my question since it was a little confusing.  Thanks!